# by mistake i will give 777 permission to home directory in aws ubuntu server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, ubuntu-18.04

I accidentally run "sudo chmod -R 777 /home" on my Ubuntu ec2 AWS instance. After that, I cannot connect to the instance anymore, neither via FTP nor via SSH. Do you have any tips for me on how I can access and change the permission?

Comment: i tried to replicate the exact situation and i can connect using `ec2 instance connect through console `and even ssh, make you you sure using correct public address of ec2 and pem key file., and security group
if ssh is not working for you `try ec2 instance connect from the console.`

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you wouldn't have anything of consequence stored on that EC2 instance so you could simply terminate it and launch a new EC2 instance to replace it.

You can, however, detach and mount the damaged EC2 instance's root volume to a second EC2 instance, make corrections, then detach and re-attach it to the original EC2 instance. See [Fixing Files on the Root EBS Volume of an EC2 Instance](https://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root/).

Not clear if this will help you, but worth reading [Amazon EC2 enables replacing root volumes for quick restoration and troubleshooting](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/ec2-enables-replacing-root-volumes-for-quick-restoration-and-troubleshooting/). This is a new feature as of April 2021.

Comment: Other options: SSM Run Command to fix it, or possibly SSM Console, if the SSM agent is running on the machine. [EC2 Serial Console](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/introducing-ec2-serial-console/).